# How to force decimal addition (#10) when adding numbers with a carry (octal issue)

Tags: scripting, floating-point

How can I get `10#1$result` to work correctly?

When creating a calculator for adding two numbers I am adding together by transversing the digits from small to large.  e.g. for adding 51 plus 51 I am adding 1+1, storing the "2", then adding 5+5, storing the "0" and then adding the 1 at the beginning.

To do this I am using result=`1$result`

However I run into problems with numbers that have 8 and 9 in them.  I discovered this recently and was able to solve it then by preceding it with 10#, e.g.

```
result=10#$((result))
```

However with the need for the "1" at the start for when I have a "10" as the result (record 0, then add the "1" at the start) I can't get the base 10 syntax 
to work right.  I've tried:

```
result=10#1$((result))
result=10#(1$((result)))
result="10#1$((result))"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct format is simply to use:

```
result=10#1$result
```